# Is there a way to use LOOKUP/VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP to return headers in EXCEL. Current formula returning wrong value

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup, lookup

My Excel workbook's purpose is to schedule workers in available time blocks:

[image: Time Sheet]

and return the number of time blocks a worker has been assigned, as well as the time block (column header) the member has been assigned to in the Work Overview

[image: []

In the work overview sheet, the column "assigned times" uses the following formula:

```
 =(IFERROR(LOOKUP(A3,Schedule!$B$3:$B$7,Schedule!$B$2:$B$2),"No Job Assigned"))
```

The goal is to search the column of cells (B3:B7) for the name in cell "A3".  When if the name appears in column, the column header is returned to the Roster Sheet, next to their name (Assigned times).

Comment: `=If(Countif(B3:B7,"John")>0, B2, "No Job Assigned")` would do the trick, I believe.

Comment: That "COUNTIF" definitely worked!  thanks for that!  it was busting my brain.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if understand 100%, but the correct counter...

It would be like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Schedule!$B$3:$F$7=A3))
```